# Mocking a void method from the same class that is being tested

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

I am trying to test a method using mockito and powermockito, this method internally calling a method which returns void, i wanted to mock this method since i dont care about the result of that method. i have been trying on this but unable to find the solution please help me on this.

I tries using powermockito as

```
SearchProcedureCodeControllerBean mock = mock(SearchProcedureCodeControllerBean.class);
PowerMockito.doNothing().when(mock).setErrorMessage((String)anyObject(), Mockito.anyList().toArray(), (String)anyObject(), (String)anyObject());
```

setErrorMessage is the void method, signature for this method is as follows

```
public void setErrorMessage(String errorName, Object[] arguments,
            String messageBundle, String componentId) {
}
```

Comment: Mocking class under the test is smell that you're doing something unusual

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stub method of a mocked object only. Tested object is definitely not mocked. With Power Mockito you can stub static methods, it's not your case. If you don't care about the method behavior just leave it like this. It`s void so it will baisically don't matter. If it does and you would like to suppress it's influence, it would mean the real problem is with the design as the class under test owns too much responsibility. Extract the method to another class and then mock it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I need one more help from you, i am trying to mock a abstract method is it possible. since it is returning null value for me

Comment: Sure you can. If you faced a problem, go a head and post another question.